# php script as cron using plesk 10.3.1

Tags: php, cron, plesk

I've been running a simple php script (which logs its running time in a text log file). From browser it runs fine, but as I use the scheduled tasks in my plesk 10.3.1 panel as follow:

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   php /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/cron/crone_test.php
```

It does run right after five minutes but does not write anything in the text file and sends me following notification messages via email:

```
php [-f from_encoding] [-t to_encoding] [-s string] [files...]
php -l
php -r encoding_alias
 -l,--list
    lists all available encodings
 -r,--resolve encoding_alias
   resolve encoding to its (Encode) canonical name
 -f,--from from_encoding
    when omitted, the current locale will be used
 -t,--to to_encoding
    when omitted, the current locale will be used
 -s,--string string
    "string" will be the input instead of STDIN or files
The following are mainly of interest to Encode hackers:
 -D,--debug          show debug information
 -C N | -c | -p      check the validity of the input
 -S,--scheme scheme  use the scheme for conversion
```

What should I add in the following line?

```
php /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/cron/crone_test.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The text you get back is the usage message of piconv. This has absolutely nothing to do with PHP, the scripting language. What you probably want to do is one of the following:

## Alternative 1: Using the PHP command line interpreter

You need to call the actual php interpreter on your system. This might be `/usr/bin/php5`, so your crontab line would look like

```
*/5 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/cron/crone_test.php
```

However not every setup has this command line interpreter installed. It might happen that only the apache module is installed.

## Alternative 2: Using an HTTP(S) request

If you don't have the right to install the command line tool, have a look if wget or curl is installed. If so, you can use them to invoke the script by sending a request to the web server.

### Using wget:

```
/usr/bin/wget -O /dev/null 'http://eblogs.co.uk/crone_test.php'
```

`-O /dev/null` tells it to save the web page generated by your script in `/dev/null`. It is a special file that basically immediately forgets all data written to it. So this parameter avoids that any new file with the web page contents is created and lies around in your server's file system.

### Using curl:

```
/usr/bin/curl -o /dev/null 'http://eblogs.co.uk/crone_test.php'
```

`-o /dev/null` has the same function here as the version with the capital O above for wget.

Comment: Oh, and by the way: Is the script on your server called 'crone_test.php', with an 'e'? Just have copied it to my answer as is. If it's a typo I would correct it in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the top of the php script:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
  your code here
?>
```

(assuming php exists at /usr/bin)

Hope that helps !

Comment: Yes, the php source is at "/usr/bin/php", I added the line #!/usr/bin/php in the beginning of the source file but it didnt do any good, still getting the same notification or error in email.
I guess we'll have to add something between the "php" and the "path"

Comment: make sure the file is marked as executable (chmod +x), since you have added the shebang (#!/usr/bin/php) you could just call it like /yourfile.php. That should make it

Comment: the /usr/bin/php alredy had 755 permissions

Comment: nope, i didnt refer to /usr/bin/php but your crone_test.php file

Comment: so you tried now to run from plesk without invoking the php in the command ?

Comment: just the same as you would run any other application: `/var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/cron/crone_test.php` , because you made it executable (chmod +x) and you already added the shebang it will run as if you would call it by `php filename.php`

Comment: I tried it as "php /var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/cron/crone_test.php" but didnt do any good, still getting the same notifications.

Comment: nope, you must call it like this `/var/www/vhosts/eblogs.co.uk/httpdocs/frostbox/cron/crone_test.php`and as i previously pointed crone_test_php must have execution permissions, this is very important

Answer (score 0):

You can use "curl" ... like this:

```
curl "http://eblogs.co.uk/crone_test.php"
```